# Is this proof that $\mathbb{N}$ is not bounded above correct?

Tags: real-analysis

The following proof is from [https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/intro_analysis_pdf/ch2.pdf](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/intro_analysis_pdf/ch2.pdf)

> If $x \in R$, then there exists $n \in N$ such that $x < n$.
>
> Suppose, for contradiction, that there exists $x \in R$ such that $x > n$ for every
> $n \in N$. Then $x$ is an upper bound of $N$, so $N$ has a supremum $M = \sup N \in R$.
> Since $n \le M$ for every $n \in N$, we have $n − 1 ≤ M − 1$ for every $n \in N$, which implies that $n \le M − 1$ for every $n \in N$. But then $M − 1$ is an upper bound of $N$, which contradicts the assumption that $M$ is a least upper bound.

I'm not sure how exactly I'm supposed to use the fact that $n-1 \le M-1$ for every $n \in N$. I thought that I could show $n-1 \le M-1 \le M$ and go from there using a similar process shown below. I did the following:

$|n| \le M$ implies that

$-M \le n \le M$

$-M + 1 \le n + 1 \le M +1$

so that

$-M \le -M + 1 \le n +1$

and

$-M \le n+1 = |n+1|$

which implies that

$-M \le n+1\le M$

and from here I can show that $n \le M-1$. I'm used to getting an interval from $|x| <M$, for example, which implies that $-M <x<M$. I'm not sure if my process is correct.

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  The cited paragraph in blocked quotes is completely done and nothing more needs doing.

Comment: It's correct, I was just trying to see how we go from $n \le M$ to $n \le M -1$

Comment: If $n-1 \le M-1$ for all natural numbers then it is true for $(n+1)-1\le M-1$ for all natural numbers.  $n$ is *not* a fixed value.  That's the whole point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure how exactly I'm supposed to use the fact that n−1≤M−1 for every n∈N.

You are thinking way too hard.  If $n-1\le M-1$ for all $n$ then it is true for  $(n+1)-1 = n \le M-1$.  So $n\le M-1$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$.

So $M-1$ is an upper bound of $N$.  But $M$ is the *least* upper bound.  And that's a contradiction.

Comment: Even if I did more than necessary, is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you need to play tricks in order to prove this; in the axiomatic treatment of the reals you get the least upper bound property, from which you can derive [the Archimedean property of the reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property#Archimedean_property_of_the_real_numbers). Once you know that you cannot have infinitely large reals, and that the naturals are contained within the reals, you should be done.